# Is it legal for a firm to time their announcements based on the stock sale times indicated in the pre-established 10b5-1 plan?

Tags: united-states, finance, insider-trading

I understand that [SEC Rule 10b5-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SEC_Rule_10b5-1) aims at reducing insider trading by having major shareholders and insiders of exchange-listed corporations trade a predetermined number of shares at a predetermined time (refer to as the "pre-established 10b5-1 plan").

Following the recent case on  [Pfizer CEO made $5.6 million stock sale on same day as COVID-19 vaccine update: filing](https://www.reuters.com/article/idUSKBN27R1Z5), I wonder the following: is it legal for a firm to time their announcements based on the stock sale times indicated in the pre-established 10b5-1 plan?

E.g., if an announcement is expected to boost the stock price, then make the announcement on the day of the sale, and conversely if an announcement is expected to shoot down the stock price, then make the announcement on the day after the sale.